# How to make a curl request using axios with curl options

Tags: node.js, curl, axios, nestjs

I have to make a curl request to jenkins to get the job done but I am not sure how to do that using axios I am currently using nestjs as my backend framework I have tried googling it not much luck If anybody please help. The curl request looks a bit like below

```
curl -u pp:11d7b5072400da385981e24283472834 -H "${JENKINS_CRUMB}" -i -X POST $JENKINS_URL/job/$JOB_NAME/buildWithParameters --user pp:1232343454564123453 --data token=123456 --data
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [axis documents](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config) you can create request like that:

```js
const JENKINS_URL = '***';
const JOB_NAME = '***';

const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  url: `${JENKINS_URL}/job/${JOB_NAME}/buildWithParameters`,
  headers: {
    JENKINS_SAMPLE_HEADER: 'jenkins_smaple_header'
  },
  withCredentials: true,
  auth: {
    username: 'pp',
    password: '11d7b5072400da385981e24283472834'
  },
  data: {
    token: '123456',
  }
};

axios (options)
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error('Error', error);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [this lovely tool](https://curlconverter.com/node-axios/) and obtained this - after fixing a couple of errors in the original request:

```
const axios = require('axios');

const response = await axios.post(
    'http://path',
    new URLSearchParams({
        'token': '123456'
    }),
    {
        auth: {
            username: 'pp',
            password: '1232343454564123453'
        }
    }
);
```

It's quite useful to help out when you don't know how to translate a request!